# How many bytes are in each cylinder?

Tags: hard-drive

Consider a hard disk with the following specifications.

```
•   3.5 in diameter 
•   3840 RPM 
•   10 platters, and 2 surfaces each platter 
•   Usable capacity: 10GB 
•   Number of cylinders: 256 
•   1 block = 4 KB 
•   20% overhead between blocks (gaps) 
•   Average seek time: 20 ms. 
Compute the following numbers: 
1.  How many bytes are in each cylinder? 
2.  How many blocks are in each cylinder?
```

Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Are you asking us to do your homework for you?

Comment: It depends on the bore and stroke, but you can always divide the total cubes by the number of cylinders.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is someone's homework

Comment: Modern Zone Bit Recording. Whatever the manufacturer makes it and variable as to location from rim. Not really a worthwhile or useful question in reality. Meant something in the days of MFM and RLL, not so much now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic math. Use [Bit Calculator - Convert between bits/bytes/kilobits/kilobytes/megabits/megabytes/gigabits/gigabytes.](http://www.matisse.net/bitcalc/)

Data given:

- Usable capacity: 10 GiB
- Number of cylinders: 256
- block = 4 KB

**How many bytes are in each cylinder?**

```
10 GiB = 10485760 kb = 10737418240 bytes
```

bytes per cylinder = Capacity in byes (10737418240) / Number of Cylinders (256)

```
10737418240 / 256 = 41943040
```

So there are **41943040** bytes in each cylinder.

**How many blocks are in each cylinder?**

```
41943040 bytes = 40960 kb
```

blocks per cylinder = kb per cylinder (40960) / 4

```
40960 / 4 = 10240
```

So there are **10240** blocks in each cylinder

Comment: Note on prefixes: disk capacity is usually expressed with decimal prefixes, so 10 GB = 10,000,000,000 B. It's not the case here because this calculation would yield a non-integer result. It would be more correct to state that disk's capacity is 10 [GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte).

Comment: Corrected answer as per comment from @gronostaj

Comment: *"41943040 bytes = 40960 kb / 4 = 10240 blocks /cylinder"* -- The final answer seems correct, but the expressions in front of it are nonsense (typos?).

Comment: Explanation added as per comment from @sawdust

Comment: Why the intermediate step? `blks per cyl` = `bytes per cyl` / `bytes per block` by **dimensional analysis**.

Comment: @sawdust I was explaining the calculation using the **op's given data**...

Answer (score 0):

you said 256 cylinders? man, that's a small hard drive....

when I go here:

http://www.rajeshvu.com/san/utils/general/CylindersToGigaByte

and type in 256 it says that it is only 240 mb. based on 512 byte blocks (or sectors) but your example is based on 4 k blocks, so you will have to take my answer and multiply it by 4 to get your answer

1024 byte blocks x 4 = is 4 k, I know there is a mistake in the calculation somewhere, but my point is nobody really does this kind of math anymore. Most PC's and Hard Drives today don't really use block addressing any more but use LBA Block addressing

Best thing to do (in the real world and not in school) is, usually, I would go to the drive manufactures web site and punch in the serial number of the hard drive and get the specs on the drive.

In the real world, we only care about the cost and the size of drive...

There are really a lot of good docs on the Internet with the history of hard drives, (this makes a good read if you are into that kind of thing) since you most likely won't find a 10 gig drive anymore...

Here is the Real Formula:

Calculation

Because modern disk drives appear to their interface as a contiguous set of logical blocks their gross capacity can be calculated by multiplying the number of blocks by the size of the block. This information is available from the manufacturer's specification and from the drive itself through use of special utilities invoking low level commands.[61][62]

The gross capacity of older HDDs can be calculated by multiplying for each zone of the drive the number of cylinders by the number of heads by the number of sectors/zone by the number of bytes/sector (most commonly 512) and then summing the totals for all zones. Some modern SATA drives will also report cylinder-head-sector (C/H/S) values to the CPU but they are no longer actual physical parameters since the reported numbers are constrained by historic operating-system interfaces.

The old C/H/S scheme has been replaced by logical block addressing. In some cases, to try to "force-fit" the C/H/S scheme to large-capacity drives, the number of heads was given as 64, although no modern drive has anywhere near 32 platters: the typical 2 TB hard disk as of 2013 has two 1 TB platters (and 4 TB drives use four platters).

This is Taken from here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive

Comment: could you explain your calculation a bit more. You say "you will have to take my answer and multiply it by 4 (and then 10) "  <--  Besides the fact that it gives approx 10GB..  Where did you derive the multiplying by 4 and then 10, can you explain that?  I see that to get his 512 byte calculation to 4096(his block size) requires multiplying by 8..as 4096/512 is 8, that adjusts his calculation for block size, though that doesn't get there. So, where did you get the *4*10(which does approx)? Can you explain?